# How to remove duplicate post in wordpress where post has different id's?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a template file there are showing my post from a certain year, it is working but there are now duplicates of some post on my site and I am not allowed to delete them. So my problem is that the generated list is showing two different post but with the same content. I have an idear that it should be possible to test if the post_title is already printet to page, but I have not succeeded in that. So now i am asking for help. Below is my template file.

```
        <?php
/* Template Name: 2012 */

get_header();

?>


<?php
    $post_titles = array();
    $year = isset($_GET['y']) ? $_GET['y'] : date('Y');
    if($year == date('Y')){
        $posts = get_newest_posts();
    }
    else{
        $posts = get_yearly_posts($year);
    } ?>
    <div class="site-content-wrapper site-content-blog-wrapper container columns clearfix archive">
    <article id="primary-wrapper" class="eight column">
    <div class="post-blog inner">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#">News <?= $year ?></a></h2>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>

    /*  here i would like a test to see if a post with a similar title already has 
        printet to page. if it has not the code below should run and print post to page. */

        <div class="archive-post">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td width="100%"><span class="STRONG"><a href="<?= bloginfo('url') ?>/?p=<?= $post->ID ?>" target="_top"><?= $post->post_title ?></a></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="norm">
                <?php if($year != date('Y')): ?>
                    <?= $post->search_plus_description ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= $post->post_excerpt ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="norm">
                    <?= $year == date('Y') ? date('d F Y', strtotime($post->post_date)) : date('d F Y', strtotime($post->publication_date)) ?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="x.gif" width="1" height="10" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Thanks for answers. I made function that that run through $post array and returns an array without duplicates. Seems to do it and I do not erase from db. Here is the code

```
function remove_duplicates(array $array){
  $tmp_array = array();
$title_array = array();
$date_array = array();
  foreach($array as $post)  
  {
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $date = $post->post_date;
     if (!(in_array($title, $title_array) && in_array($date, $date_array)))
     {
       $tmp_array[] = $post;
    $title_array[] = $title;
    $date_array[] = $date;
     }
  }
  return $tmp_array;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend removing duplicate entries from the database, instead of using a workaround.

Comment: Me to, but i am not allowed to do that

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
global $wpdb;

$duplicate_titles = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} GROUP BY post_title HAVING COUNT(*) > 1");

foreach( $duplicate_titles as $title ) {
   $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title=%s", $title ) ); 
   // Iterate over the second ID with this post title till the last
   foreach( array_slice( $post_ids, 1 ) as $post_id ) {
       wp_delete_post( $post_id, true ); // Force delete this post
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, will this delete from database? It is not allowed for me to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your custom sql query on wp_posts table to find the ID of posts having distinct title and content. After that you can use WP_Query to use these ID's to display posts in the template loop.

i am posting an example which gives me distinct posts based on title:

```
$sql = 'select ID,post_title,post_type,post_status from wp_posts group by post_title having (post_status)="publish" AND (post_status)="publish"';
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
    $distinctIds = array();
    foreach($results as $result){
            $distinctIds[] = $result['ID'];
    }
$args = array('post_type' => 'post','post__in'=> $distinctIds);
$distinct_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if($distinct_posts->have_posts()) : 
    while($distinct_posts->have_posts()) : 
    $distinct_posts->the_post();
    // your stuff related to post
    // echo content etc..
   endwhile;
endif;
```

Of course we can use custom parameters in WP_Query for more refinement.
Hope this will help.